# Windsor castle: how do you set log4net filePath dynamically through LoggingFacility

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, castle

I am using castle logger using log4net to log. Here is my install setup. I have config file called `log4net.config`, where all log4net setting are created.

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
          f =>
              f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.Log4net)
               .WithConfig(Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, "log4net.config")));
              container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
```

In `log4net.config` file i have `filePath` set as:

```
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileCompositeAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:\LoggerFolder\MyLogFile.log" />
      .....
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

To use this, I have `ILogger` logger and use `logger.Error("xyz");`

Everything is working perfectly.

Now i want to change the log file path from "`c:\LoggerFolder\MyLogFile.log`" to something else, during run time, when a user defines that path.

**How can I change this path dynamically, when the application is running?**

Answer (score 0):

Log4net is loaded in surveillance mode with this syntax; any change to the configuration file will be observed and the configuration file will be reloaded. So in order to change the log file path, just change the file content to set the new log file path.

You can observe this behavior by changing some settings manually, e.g. the folder name in which log files are written

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I thought about this (once user defines a new path/file name, then open and modify log4net.config file to update the filePath). My only concern was if for some reason application does not have access to modify this file, then what. This may never happen, but just in case. This is the reason I am looking for different solution.